# Torsion sheaves

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space. The usual definition of torsion-free sheaf is that sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{R}$-modules over $X$ (where $\mathcal{R}$ is a sheaf of rings over $X$) such that $\mathcal{F}(U)$ has no torsion elements.

There are many cases in which a nontrivial sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ could vanish over open sets $\mathcal{F}(U)$, and then, the only element there is zero. How does the definition handle this situation?

In other words: is the trivial ring accepted to be torsion-free in this context?

Comment: Generally, torsion-free means that the only torsion element is $0$, i.e. there is no nontrivial torsion (note that $\mathcal F(U)$ always has $0$ as a torsion element, so the usual definition of torsion-free sheaves the way you state it means no sheaf can be torsion-free).

Comment: Typically a module is said to be torsion free if the only element annihilated by a non zerodivisor is zero. The zero module is a torsion free for all rings, and the the zero module is the only torsion free module for the zero ring (in fact the only module at all).